# Magento2 Radio button product custom options

Tags: magento-2.1

Adding Radio button to product custom options drop down field, and only one radio button select for n number of add value fields at a time in magento2.

Find the screen shot:
[image]

Comment: clerify your problem.

Comment: What used of that radio button there? can you specify in detail?

Comment: For dropdown field in admin which option we selected radio button that option will select by default for that drop down in  front-end